# change column name based on a match to another data frame

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a df (foo) with subject characteristics then some genomic data (in the form of enzyme commission numbers or ECs if that is important).

```
sample  ca_avg  id  age 1.1.1.1     1.1.1.100   1.1.1.12
124-5   1003    124 80  0           0.0001      0.654
```

I would like to change the enzyme commission numbers to their actual names. I imported a .txt to a df (enames) which holds the key to convert ECs -> names with a file that has more ECs than are actually in foo.

```
ec_num      1.1.1.1 1.1.1.100   1.1.1.102   1.1.1.103   1.1.1.108
ec_name     adh     oacp        3dr         lt3h        c3d
```

I would like to replace foo's column name with the ec_name (if available), otherwise, leave the colname alone like so:

```
sample  ca_avg  id  age adh oacp    1.1.1.12
124-5   1003    124 80  0   0.0001  0.654
```

The first thing I tried was to find the intersect between the dataframes:

`common_col <- intersect(colnames(foo), colnames(enames))`

I then tried to do many iterations of

`if (colnames(foo) %in% common_col){ colnames(foo) <- colnames(enames)}`

but it isn't working.

Anything I try after this for conditional renaming fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this what the column names actually look like? R doesn't like numeric column names and typically adds an "X" if you try to import numeric column names (i.e. `1.1.1.100` becomes `X1.1.1.100`)

Comment: Yes, that is what the columns like, @Jan Boyer.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
# example datasets
foo = data.frame(x=1,
                 y=2,
                 z=3)

enames = data.frame(y = "YY",
                    z = "ZZ", stringsAsFactors = F)

# see foo
foo

#   x y z
# 1 1 2 3

# keep common column names
common_col = intersect(names(foo), names(enames))

# replace common column names in foo with corresponding values from enames
names(foo)[names(foo) %in% common_col] = enames[common_col]

# check foo again
foo

#   x YY ZZ
# 1 1  2  3
```

You can also use `colnames` instead of `names` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks @AntoniosK. Your solution is getting me closer to the right track. The weird thing that is happening is that even though common_col is operating correctly on my real data (I end up with the intended intersect), when I do the replacement step `names(foo)[names(foo) %in% common_col] = enames[common_col]`, the matching col_names are being renamed to `1`. Any idea what might be doing this? Thanks again for your willingness to answer.

Comment: Check if your process is using factor variables, or character variables for the dataset `enames`. You should have character variables.

Comment: No, the column types of the dataset `enames`. Seems you have some factor variables and when the replacement takes place the factor variable becomes a number (1 in your case).

Comment: Not sure how it's possible to have character variables and then get `1` which is a number. Can you run `enames[] = lapply(enames, as.character)` in the beginning and the rest of the code as it is and check the output? This piece of code will make sure your variables are not factors.

Comment: That extra step did it! Thanks so much, @AntoniosK!